# cx_freeze: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, character, cx-freeze

the cx_freeze notes error:

```
module.code = compile(codeString, path, "exec
  File "update.py", line 1
    \ufeffimport os
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

**cx_freeze version**: `cx_Freeze-4.2.3.win32-py3.1  ,  python version:python-3.1.3**`

no matter using the comand or step.py to compile this code,it always note the err:"`invalid character in identifier`".I had delete all character which wasn't English.and the file path was English too.
ps:I have tried to compile a "helloWorld.py",it succeed.

please help me,I'm a fresh learning python.

the code was used to copy some files to the path I write in the config file. and the code runing no error.

Comment: the error is in `update.py` file, did you remove invalid characters from that file?

Comment: Does your `import os` line have a unicode space in front of it?

Comment: to Ashwini Chaudhary :yes i did

Answer (score 2):

`0xfeff` is a Unicode byte order mark. Save `update.py` as UTF-8 without a byte order mark. (UTF-8 should not have a BOM to begin with, but some editors add one anyway.)

Comment: i copy the code to a new file and compile,it succeed. thank you!

Comment: but when i runing the exe file,it traceback:  File "C:\Python31\lib\encodings\ascii.py", line 26, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 2: ordinal
not in range(128)
my python installed in d:

Comment: why the exealble file go c: to search the encoding package.i compile it by using the comand"csfreeze --target-dir dist". is there anyother way to do that, and will not search the encoding package in c: ??